# Set Height for MapView in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I am new to flutter, I have tried to implement the MapView in flutter by reffering the following example from Git

**"flutter_google_map_view-master"**

By tapping the static view , MapView Loaded in fullscreen view but I want to set height and width for Map View.

Answer (score -1):

It's not available in flutter SDK. Google map by default open in

Flutter team working for custom height and width.

Comment: We can set height for the container, can we bring the map view within the container. Is it Possible ?

Comment: No, Because active google map open in activity for Android.

Comment: Is there a link for the issue on repo? @V.Vairaganesh